# How can I change the default GECOS fields under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I was wondering if there was a way to change the default GECOS fields on a user. Now, I don't mean change their name, number, shell, etc. What I mean is change the field-type/name itself.

Like, for example, since I never use the "Work-Phone" field, could I say, rename it to something else, like "Address" ?

Also, is it possible to add completely new field entries as well?

All I could really find through searching is how to change the fields that are already set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially the only software that cares about the GECOS field content (beyond the first comma which delimits the full name) for *anything* is `adduser`, `chfn` and similar program for *updating* the pasword file. To a very good approximation, nobody *uses* these subfields, so you're free to put whatever you like in them.

The hard-coded prompt strings in `adduser` or option letters in `chfn` probably can't be changed -- they are conventional uses anyway, and there is nothing like a central definition of subfield names anywhere. But don't let that stop you from storing "user's favorite food" in the field ostensibly for work phone numbers if that floats your boat.

Note, however, that if you want to store any real information about users for more than toy purposes, `/etc/passwd` is most probably not the place to do it. Use a separate user-information database which is easier to make Unicode clean.

Comment: So basically you're saying if I wanted to store user information, say for a small business, beyond that of what the GECOS fields are then I should create a new database and come up with some scripts that would search for the information and add/edit/delete it as well.

Comment: @Arkevius: I'd strengthen that and say even if some of what you store is something that the traditional GECOS field doesn't have room for, keep /etc/passwd away from that. It is too critical a piece of infrastructure to use for ordinary humdrum administration -- too much it at risk if an update leaves garbage in the file, and there's no telling which ancient, crusty, but vital piece of the system will try to parse it and barf at high-bit characters if someone tries to use it for real-world data with non-English or accented letters in it.

Comment: So leave /etc/passwd alone, got it, haha. I'll just have to implement my own, separate solution away from the passwd file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The GECOS field is not only for "crusty" things. It is actively used on Ubuntu for user-specific system configuration. For example, the way to set a different default `umask` for an individual user is to have an entry `umask=` in the GECOS field. See the `pam_umask` man page for more details. So it's important to maintain the GECOS field properly. You can't just do whatever you want.